# Wordpress hacked to include backlinks

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, eval

**Symptoms:**

- some weird links to different shopping sites insertet on startpage
- mydomain.com/page_name=XYZ&id=123 redirects to different shopping sites (hint by a comment)

**Already tried:**

- found PHP Entry eval(base64_decode('ICRmZl9vdXRsaW5rX2ZpbGVf... in footer.php, which was responsible for some of the weird links injection --> deleted that
- File & DB Search for "eval", "page_name" and other suspected keywords --> didnt find something obviously wrong

**BUT THERE MUST BE SOME MORE BACKDOOR**

the hint with the page_name and id VARS (symptoms) in combination was brought by an anonymous comment (strange?)

anybody got the same problem or knows a solution?

Comment: Flagged for Server forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats strange! I advise to search via shell for files with large hashstrings:

```
find ./ -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep '[a-zA-Z0-9]\{400\}'
```

That will give you a list. In my case in my root-folder was a file include.class.php located with much stuff of the backdoor. Some more files (with crypted names) were located in my wp-includes/ folder. They seem to be responsible for the backdoor-file creating. Remove the backdoor file and the crypted!

Have fun :)

Comment: woooow! Thats it! removed the greped files and the links are gone!

Answer (score 0):

Check [Wordpress Codex: Help I think I've been hacked](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked). This is the best advice you will find.